# Connect an Arduino Due native USB port to an Xbee Explorer based on an FTDI 232R chip

Tags: arduino, xbee, usbserial, ftdi, cdc

I want to connect an [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) to an [Arduino Due](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardDue) using a Sainsmart USB Explorer. I have looked everywhere and cannot find any information on doing this.

I have successfully connected an [Arduino Mega](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega) using a Sainsmart USB Host Shield using the USB Host Shield Lib at https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0, but I need to use the XBee with a GLCD shield, and I cannot stack a USB shield on the LCD shield. It seems that only a mouse or keyboard is supported by the Arduino USB host library.

Answer (score 0):

by default FTDI x232 family chips only support serial mode (that's why a mouse or keyboard will work) but don't support MPSSE mode; the driver does not support that.

MSPPE mode is used for other serial protocols like I2C, SPI or bitbang. So if you need SPI/I2C over usb to talk to your XBEE device, you need a library which does that your you.

FTDI ofers their own D2xx dirver library which is not open source and can cause conflicts with other USB devices because it replaces the standard driver library. Or you can have a look at [libmpsse](http://code.google.com/p/libmpsse/) which is open source (And I personally recommend).